# ReactJS + FineUploader: Error if template resides in render() function using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fine-uploader

If the template script tag resides in the render function of my component, I get following errors:

In Firefox: |TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object.|
In Chrome: |Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of null|

If the template script tag is placed in a static part of the document, then everything works. Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
let React = require('react');
let ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

let qq = require('fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js');

let FineUploadInputControl = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() { return { shared: this.props.shared }; },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: this.fineUploaderElement,
            template: this.fineUploaderTemplate,
            //template: 'qq-template-gallery',
            request: {
                endpoint: '/server/uploads'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            }
        });
     },

    render: function() {
        return (
             <div>

                <script
                    ref={(ref) => this.fineUploaderTemplate = ref}
                    type="text/template" id="qq-template-gallery">

                <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
                    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                        <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                        <div>Upload a file</div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                        <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
                    </span>
                    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
                        <li>
                            <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                            <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale />
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
                            <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                                <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                                Retry
                            </button>

                            <div class="qq-file-info">
                                <div class="qq-file-name">
                                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                                </div>
                                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text" />
                                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                                    <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                                    <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                                    <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </dialog>

                    <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
                        </div>
                    </dialog>

                    <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
                        </div>
                    </dialog>
                </div>

            </script>


            <div
                ref={(ref) => this.fineUploaderElement = ref}
                id="fine-uploader-gallery">
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
});

module.exports = FineUploadInputControl;
```

I add a stack trace from Firefox, maybe it helps:

```
[197]/qq.toElement()
profile_new_discrete_single_view.component..

[197]/qq.Templating/parseAndGetTemplate()
profile_new_discrete_single_view.component..

[197]/qq.Templating()
profile_new_discrete_single_view.component..

[197]/qq.FineUploader()
profile_new_discrete_single_view.component..

componentDidMount()
profile_new_discrete_single_view.component..

.notifyAll()
vendor.bundle..

ON_DOM_READY_QUEUEING.close()
vendor.bundle..

Mixin.closeAll()
vendor.bundle..

Mixin.perform()
vendor.bundle..

batchedMountComponentIntoNode()
vendor.bundle..

Mixin.perform()
vendor.bundle..

ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates()
vendor.bundle..

batchedUpdates()
vendor.bundle..

ReactMount._renderNewRootComponent()
vendor.bundle..

ReactMount._renderSubtreeIntoContainer()
vendor.bundle..

ReactMount.render()
vendor.bundle..

[0]()
profile_new_discrete_single_view.component..

__webpack_require__()
vendor.bundle..

webpackJsonpCallback()
vendor.bundle..
```

Comment: Where exactly is the code failing? You've left out stack traces, and those are needed to provide further help.

Comment: Thank you Ray, I just added one.

Comment: What specific line(s) are involved? That isn't included in your stack trace

Comment: Without more information about the issue, I'm not sure how I can help further. But I've been developing a full React wrapper for Fine Uploader UI over the last few months. It's almost usable. Follow progress at https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader.

Answer (score 1):

JSX doesn't do well with `<script>` tags because it doesn't really make sense in terms of rendering DOM and detecting changes. [This Github ticket](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/654) has more information.

If you need to render template to the DOM, you can try using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<script 
    ref={(ref) => this.fineUploaderTemplate = ref}
    type="text/template" id="qq-template-gallery">
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
       <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
       ...
    `}}
 />
```